# FileServiceFactory getBlobKey throws IllegalArgumentException

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, blobstore

I am trying to use `FileService` to create a file on Blobstore.

Code look as follows:

```
public static BlobKey save(String mimeType, String value, String filename) throws IOException
{
    FileService svc = FileServiceFactory.getFileService();
    AppEngineFile file = filename == null ? svc.createNewBlobFile(mimeType) : svc.createNewBlobFile(mimeType, filename);
    key = svc.getBlobKey(file); //throws exception
}
```

But I get the following exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: creation_handle: String properties must be 500 characters or less.  
Instead, use com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Text, which can store strings of any length.
    at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DataTypeUtils.checkSupportedSingleValue(DataTypeUtils.java:242)
    at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DataTypeUtils.checkSupportedValue(DataTypeUtils.java:207)
    at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DataTypeUtils.checkSupportedValue(DataTypeUtils.java:173)
    at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Query$FilterPredicate.<init>(Query.java:900)
    at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Query$FilterOperator.of(Query.java:75)
    at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Query.addFilter(Query.java:351)
    at com.google.appengine.api.files.FileServiceImpl.getBlobKey(FileServiceImpl.java:329)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed the problem.

I had to ensure the following:

1. I call the `openWriteChannel`
2. Write some content (optional)
3. Close the channel (`close` or `closeFinally`)
4. And then call `getBlobKey`

This ensures that `getCachedKey` method is called (I guess so) or `createHandle` is available.

I was, earlier, trying to `getBlobKey` before writing content.