# Failing for Larger Input Files Only: FileServiceFactory getBlobKey throws IllegalArgumentException

Tags: java, google-app-engine, blobstore

I have a Google App Engine App that converts CSV to XML files.  It works fine for small XML inputs, but refuses to finalize the file for larger inputed XML.  The XML is read from, and the resulting csv files are written to, many times before finalization, over a long-running (multi-day duration) task. My problem is different than this [FileServiceFactory getBlobKey throws IllegalArgumentException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15251092/fileservicefactory-getblobkey-throws-illegalargumentexception) , since my code works fine both in production and development with small input files.  So it's not that I'm neglecting to write to the file before closing/finalizing.  However, when I attempt to read from a larger XML file. The input XML file is ~150MB, and the resulting set of 5 CSV files is each much smaller (perhaps 10MB each).  I persisted the file urls for the new csv files, and even tried to close them with some static code, but I just reproduce the same error, which is

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: creation_handle: String properties must be 500 characters or less.  Instead, use com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Text, which can store strings of any length.
    at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DataTypeUtils.checkSupportedSingleValue(DataTypeUtils.java:242)
    at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DataTypeUtils.checkSupportedValue(DataTypeUtils.java:207)
    at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DataTypeUtils.checkSupportedValue(DataTypeUtils.java:173)
    at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Query$FilterPredicate.<init>(Query.java:900)
    at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Query$FilterOperator.of(Query.java:75)
    at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Query.addFilter(Query.java:351)
    at com.google.appengine.api.files.FileServiceImpl.getBlobKey(FileServiceImpl.java:329)
```

But I know that it's not a String/Text data type issue, since I am already using similar length file service urls for the previous successful attempts with smaller files.  It also wasn't an issue for the other stackoverflow post I linked above.  I also tried putting one last meaningless write before finalizing, just in case it would help as it did for the other post, but it made no difference.  So there's really no way for me to debug this...  Here is my file closing code that is not working.  It's pretty similar to the Google how-to example at http://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/blobstore/overview#Writing_Files_to_the_Blobstore  .

```
log.info("closing out file 1");
try {
    //locked set to true
    FileWriteChannel fwc1 = fileService.openWriteChannel(csvFile1, true);
    fwc1.closeFinally();
} catch (IOException ioe) {ioe.printStackTrace();}

// You can't get the blob key until the file is finalized
BlobKey blobKeyCSV1 = fileService.getBlobKey(csvFile1);
log.info("csv blob storage key is:" + blobKeyCSV1.getKeyString());
csvUrls[i-1] = blobKeyCSV1.getKeyString();
break;
```

At this point, I just want to finalize my new blob files for which I have the urls, but cannot.  How can I get around this issue, and also, what may be the cause?  Again, my code works for small files (~60 kB), but the input file of ~150MB fails).  Thank you for any advice on what is causing this or how to get around it!  Also, how long will my unfinalized files stick around for, before being deleted?

Comment: See Issue 8932 https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=8932, we are working on it.

Comment: Thanks Sebastian, I appreciate that you are working on it. However, I think my issue is different, and more like this issue: http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=9035 since I *have* been successfully using the longer blob file urls in my code (I persist them in a database and they work fine with my code). I think the exception's verbose description is somehow misleading, since it seems any failure in the FileServiceImpl.getBlobKey leads to this message from datastore.DataTypeUtils.checkSupportedSingleValue,which I think is a blanket misdiagnosis of the checking code.

Comment: To expound, my new blob file name lengths are constant, yet the blobs fail to finalize for larger sized blobs.

Comment: I think both issues are related. You are in fact able to finalize your file. The problem arises when you are getting the blobKey.

Comment: Sebastian, good point; I do get no exception from finalization.  But, why I still don't feel it's fully finalized is that the finalized files do not appear in the App Engine Dashboard Blob Viewer screen's list of finalized files.

Comment: It may be resolved.  Will test soon.  https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/google-appengine/NmjYYLuSizo

Comment: Issue resolved by Google's fix: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-appengine/NmjYYLuSizo

Answer (score 0):

This issue was a bug in the Java MapReduce and Files API, which was recently fixed by Google.  Read announcement here: groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-appengine/NmjYYLuSizo